# Line-height won't work

Tags: css

I've got a problem that's bothering me. The line-height seems to be based on the inherit by a previous font-size.

The code within the div "textruta" is generated by CKeditor, therefore a lot of crap code..

**EDIT:**

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
  <title> timesheets.js :: Slideshow Engine </title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Frijole' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
}
</style>
<div id="textruta" class="textruta" style="width: 280px; height: 116px; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 120px; visibility: visible;">
<span id="previewtext1">
<p>
<span style="font-size:28px">
    <span style="font-family:frijole">
        <span style="background-color:#FFFF00">Hello There!</span>
    </span>
<br><br>
    <span style="font-size:18px">
        <span style="font-size:26px">
            <span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color:#FF0000">123:-</span>
         <br><span style="font-size:18px"><em><span style="background-color:#FF0000">(234:-)</span></em>
         </span>
     </span>
     </span>
     </span>
     </span>
</p>
</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The result:**

[image]

**Desired result:**

[image]

Any ideas?

[Here's a link to the test page](http://centrumkanalen.se/btv/add/mall/preview/preview11test.php)

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/201429)

Comment: remove br but I don't think for this design you have proper html code here. 1. Remove br 2. Increase height of div as height:125px; This might look close to the output you are looking for

Comment: I now anOG.. Sorry about that. First and last time I'm doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You have some serious looking code here:

```
<div id="textruta" class="textruta" 
     style="padding:10px; height:116px; text-align: left; 
            left:160px; top:100px; width:280px;">
    <p>
    <span style="font-size:28px">
    <span style="font-family:frijole">
    <span style="background-color:#FFFF00">
      Hello There!
    </span>
    </span>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
    <span style="font-size:18px"><span style="font-size:26px">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="background-color:#FF0000">
      123:-
    </span>
    <br></br>
    <span style="font-size:18px">
    <em>
    <span style="background-color:#FF0000">
      (234:-)
    </span>
    </em>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

You see these hard coded line breaks: `<br><br>`, that is probably the cause of the extra white space.

You must be using some type of WYSISWG editor to generate this stuff, it is rather incredible!

Comment: Yeah I know, much crap code there :) It's generated by CKEDITOR. Even after I remove the <br><br>, the space between 123:- and (234:-) is to long

Comment: There are so many nested spans and font-sizes that it is hard to know where to begin.  You may have to go into the code view and clean up this stuff first, otherwise, tweaking line-height may not help.

Answer (score 1):

Wierd!

**I solved it by changing the head:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Into:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Anyone know why? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
.hellomessage {
margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

and it's ok I went to it and the code is kinda long

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

yes the 
 html item create extra space  , if you can move out from html or you can remove element into css

```
br {
  display: none;
}
```

but it's not recommend to do thet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, (semantics here).  Set your the textruta div/class to overflow hidden.  You don't want anything that's meant to be inside the container to be outside right?  So that's a good start.

I don't prefer line-height for your method, but I don't know exactly what you're trying to do.

Anyways, if you set the top paragraphs line-height to some sort of percentage...(Which may have been your mistake, perhaps you set it in the wrong spot or didn't user pecentages).  It works perfectly fine.  As such:

```
.textruta{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.textruta > p{
  line-height: 80%;
}
```